# Failure to pass variables/values to another view controller (not working)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Object: change the label's text in ViewControllerB

(In the ViewControllerA.m)

```
- (IBAction)ReturnToMenu
{
    ViewControllerB *ViewControllerB =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];
    ViewControllerB.scorelabel.text=@"WHY IS IT NOT WORKING";
    [self presentViewController:GameOverViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Well, this isn't working. I've exhausted all my options. This is such an elementary question, but please help me out.

P.S. @"Why is it not working" is just a temporary thing, a variable from ViewControllerA is supposed to take its place.

P.P.S. I tried out [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1), but it didn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Why didn't you comment in the previous question you'd asked? 
Did you try what I had suggested?

Comment: Possible duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311142/how-to-access-variables-of-other-classes-in-objective-c-ios/20311255#20311255

Comment: @Neeku Sorry, It's just that the post was filled with negativity and I really didn't want to go back there :( And yes, as you can see, I tried exactly what you told me. It is not working.

Comment: It's not what I said. Just try making an instance of the ViewController, away from the storyboard.

Comment: Just making an instance of the viewcontroller didn't seem to work. Doesn't it just make "ANOTHER" instance? That is, I am playing with another object's variable, not the actual view that I generated?

Comment: edit: Thanks, I think the problem wasn't in instantiating, but in accessing the label directly. It's not supposed to work for some reason?

Comment: Check out my answer. That way, you'll always have only one instance, and the property must be passed safely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, try this:

In your `ViewController1.h` that the property `score` is declared, add this:

`+ (ViewController1 *) sharedController;`

In your `ViewController1.m` add this method:

```
+ (ViewController1 *)sharedController
{
    static ViewController1* staticVar = nil;

    if (staticVar == nil)
        staticVar = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    return staticVar;
}
```

Now, where ever in other ViewControllers you need something from `ViewController1`, import the header, and then get the property like this:

`[[ViewController1 sharedController] score]`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was busy uploading it to the app store (although it might get rejected heh). Thanks, it worked! I didn't think about the class method, I probably should read a book from the start when I have the time. Have a nice day!

Comment: syntax error and type mismatch: `[[ViewController1 sharedController] score] = @"I hope it works this time!";`

Comment: @vikingosegundo Edit applied.

Comment: this is still an syntax error `[[ViewController1 sharedController] score] = 100;`

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to manipulate another view controller's views directly. It's bad design, and in many cases (like yours) it doesn't work.

Instead of setting a label's text, add a string property "score". Set that after instantiating the VC.

Then, in "ViewController8"s viewWillAppear method, install the score property into the label.

Problem solved.

Comment: OH MY GOD. My 3 hour adventure came to an end. You are a life saver.  Oh god thank you so much oh god

Answer (score 0):

Here I present a modal view controller from my main view controller to show locations which I previously got from foursquare api.

```
    LocationPickerVC *vc = (LocationPickerVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modal"];
    if([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(setLocations:) ])
            vc.locations = items;
    [self.formSheetController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[EDIT]

Make sure you set storyboard id in your storyboard (for the code below it is "modal"). Also my LocationPickerVC has this interface.

```
    @interface LocationPickerVC : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
    @property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *locations;
    @end
```